# Oracle can log into SQLPLUS using HR account but unable to log in using SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I've just spun up the Oracle developer day VM and unlocked the HR account using:

```
ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED BY password ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

If I try to log into sqlplus using sqlplus hr/hr@0.0.0.0:1521/cdb1 I get invalid password, then I enter hr and hr and am authenticated? See below:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ sqlplus hr/hr@0.0.0.0:1521/cdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Sat Dec 12 16:04:18 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name: hr
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Sat Dec 12 2015 16:03:51 -08:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```

Next I open up SQL Developer and try to make a new connection however which is when I get  an invalid username / password error:

> Status : Failure -Test Failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password;
>   logon denied

Screenshot:

[image]

The only other relevant information that I can think of is that the instructions say to connect to service name PDB1 however that generates the errror:

> Status : Failure -Test Failed: IO ERROR: The network adapter could not
>   establish a network connection

I can however create a connection to CDB1 using the system account.

Any ideas?

***EDITS****

> [oracle@localhost ~]$ env | grep ORAC ORACLE_SID=cdb1
>   ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1

Comment: You sure you got the right password?

Comment: @sstan I can log into sqlexpress with the same password, so I assume so.

Comment: What is the command you use to connect to the db instance using sqlplus?

Comment: @sstan I just type sqlplus  enter > username enter > password enter

Comment: If you don't specify any connection information when typing your sqlplus command, how can you be sure that you are connecting to the same database?  Check your environment variables, do you have a value for `ORACLE_SID`?  IF yes, what is it?  IF no, check your registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle\Key_[xxx]Home`. Look for a registry key called `ORACLE_SID`. What is the value?

Comment: @sstan ORACLE_SID=cdb1

Comment: @sstan Also I'm using linux.

Comment: In SQLDeveloper, try entering `cdb1` in the `SID` textbox instead of `Service name`.  That should do the same thing as your sqlplus command.

Comment: @sstan No such luck. I can connect using the service name and the system account, however I'm getting the invalid username/password error when connecting as hr

Comment: If the db is on the same machine that you're logging on from, shouldn't your IP address by 127.0.0.1:1521?

Comment: @BobJarvis I've tried 127.0.0.1 as well as local host, I can connect... just unable to authenticate.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using SID instead of service_name? I think cdb1 is sid not service_name.

Comment: try add string USE_SID_AS_SERVICE_listener=on to listener.ora file and restart listener. @DurgaViswanathGadiraju may be right.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora` file for the `pdb1` database? Something like this:

```
PDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host_name>.home.network)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = pdb1)
    )
  )
```

Then in `sqldeveloper` service name use `pdb1.your_host_name.home.network`.

after that reload `listner` with:

```
lsnrctl reload
```

to confirm

```
lsnrctl status
```

see if that helps.